# 辞書参照でuse of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

下記のコードを書きました。

```
let list = ["A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5]
for (key:value) in list {
    print("\(key),\(value)")
}
```

コンパイルで「Use of unresolved identifier 'key'」というエラーになります。
意味は「'key'は宣言されていません」ですが、見る限り宣言されており、エラーの意味がわかりません。
原因及び対処方法についてご教示願います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(key:value)` と書かれていますが、 `(key,value)` の誤りではないでしょうか？

```
let list = ["A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5]
for (key,value) in list {
    print("\(key),\(value)")
}
```

参考 [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2): Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID117)